# Membership store VB.NET helper class

Tags: asp.net, winforms, membership

I need to use the standard ASP.NET membership database tables in plain winform projects, and I DO NOT WANT to add the ASP.NET dll, because my app must run with .NET Client framework, and not full framework.

Does somebody knows of a helper class that links to ASP.NET tables in plain vanilla VB ot c# code?
I mean with functions equivalent to CreateNewUser, CheckUserCredentials, isUserinRole, RoleList etc...

Comment: Why do you want/need to use the asp.net membership provider for a winforms project?

Answer (score 0):

The membership provider is part of ASP.NET, if you want to use it you'll have to link against that DLL.

If you can't, you'll have to build it yourself or use a third-party utility which does it for you.

Comment: I believe his/her question states this. They were just wondering if there was a library that was already made/implemented that did this.

Comment: Can I then link against the DLL and INCLUDE it in my project, so that on the user PC, I do not need the full monty framework?